# No Edges in output file using CannyEdgeDetection.java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, edge-detection

Using the defaults, and the same source image from the first example on the website: http://www.tomgibara.com/computer-vision/canny-edge-detector I am getting a pure black image as my out.jpg.  The dimensions are correct, but no edges are detected.

Can someone please show me how to replicate the first example?

My Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CannyCmd
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        BufferedImage img = null;

        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("in.jpg"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
        }


        CannyEdgeDetector detector = new CannyEdgeDetector();
        detector.setSourceImage(img);
        detector.process();
        BufferedImage edges = detector.getEdgesImage();

        File saveFile = new File("out.jpg");

        try 
        {
            ImageIO.write(edges, "jpg", saveFile);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {} 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 File saveFile = new File("out.png"); 
 ImageIO.write(edges, "png", saveFile);
```

Comment: A comment on how this helps solve the problem would be helpful.